# Compressed UTF-8

Tags: code-golf

In the UTF-8 encoding bytes of the Form `10******` can only appear within multi-byte sequences, with the length of the sequence already being determined by the first byte.
When UTF-8 text is split within a multi-byte UTF-8 character sequence, this prevents that the second part of the sequence is wrongly detected as another character.
While in for normal Text files this error-checking is a good idea (and prevents unwanted ASCII control characters/null-bytes from appearing in the byte-stream), for code-golf this redundancy is just wasting bits.

Your task is to write **two** programs or functions, one decoder and one encoder converting between code-points and "compressed UTF-8",
defined the following way:

```
1 byte sequence:
bytes 0x00 to 0xbf  -> code-points 0x00 -> 0xbf

2 byte sequence  (code-points 0x00 -> 0x1fff):
0b110AAAAA 0bBBCCCCCC
-> code-point 0b (BB^0b10) AAAAA CCCCCC

3 byte sequence (code-points 0x00 -> 0xfffff):
0b1110AAAA 0bBBCCCCCC 0bDDEEEEEE
-> code-point 0b (BB^10) (DD^10) AAAA CCCCCC EEEEEE

4 byte sequence (code-points 0x00 -> 0x7ffffff):
0b11110AAA 0bBBCCCCCC 0bDDEEEEEE 0bFFGGGGGG
-> code-point 0b (BB^10) (DD^10) (FF^10) AAA CCCCCC EEEEEE GGGGGG
```

Or in short form: The compressed UTF-8 code-point for a sequence of bytes, is the regular UTF-8 code-point for that byte-sequence, with the difference of the high two bits and `0b10` prepended on the start of the number.

Examples:

```
decode:
[] -> []
[0xf0, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80] -> [0x00]
[0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74] -> [0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74]
[0xbb, 0xb5, 0xba, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0xab] -> [0xbb, 0xb5, 0xba, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0xab]
[0xc2, 0xbb, 0xc2, 0xb5, 0xc2, 0xba, 0xc2, 0xa9, 0xc2, 0xbf, 0xc2, 0xab] -> [0xbb, 0xb5, 0xba, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0xab]
[0xe2, 0x84, 0x95, 0xc3, 0x97, 0xe2, 0x84, 0x95] -> [0x2115, 0xd7, 0x2115]
[0xf0, 0x9f, 0x8d, 0x8f, 0xf0, 0x9f, 0x92, 0xbb] -> [0x1f34f, 0x1f4bb]
[0xef, 0x8d, 0xcf, 0xef, 0x92, 0xfb]             -> [0x1f34f, 0x1f4bb]

encode:
[] -> []
[0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74] -> [0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74]
[0xbb, 0xb5, 0xba, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0xab] -> [0xbb, 0xb5, 0xba, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0xab]
[0x2115, 0xd7, 0x2115] -> [0xe2, 0x84, 0x95, 0xc3, 0x97, 0xe2, 0x84, 0x95]
[0x1f34f, 0x1f4bb] -> [0xef, 0x8d, 0xcf, 0xef, 0x92, 0xfb]
// [0x1f34f, 0x1f4bb]=[0b1_1111_001101_001111,0b1_1111_010010_111011]
// [0xef, 0x8d, 0xcf, 0xef, 0x92, 0xfb]=[0b11101111,0b10001101,0b11001111,0b11101111,0b10010010,0b11111011]
```

### Rules

- You are allowed to use your languages internal string representation instead of code-point arrays for input/output
- When encoding a code-point you should return the shortest sequence representing that code-point
- The input may contain multiple code-points / bytes representing multiple code-points
- You only need to handle code-points in the range (0x00 to 0x10ffff)
- You score will be the sum of the lengths of the two programs
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution wins

Comment: That's not the only convenience that you get from UTF-8, for instance it's compatible with null-terminated strings but your encoding can have embedded nulls e.g. `[0x80000]` becomes `[0xe0, 0x00, 0x80]`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES10), 228 bytes

This code is solely based on bitwise operations. There may be a better way with some built-ins. At any rate, I can't say I'm very happy with it.

### Decoder (105 bytes)

```javascript
a=>a.flatMap(i=v=>i--?(n=n<<6|v&63|(v&192^128)<<5*s-4*i,i?[]:n):(s=i=(v>>4)**4>>14)?(n=v&~0>>>26+s,[]):v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJBTsMwELz3FXtAjV3SKEnTtCm1e@LIiWMUhJPGJagkqImsSlBegMSFI/yD9/QDPKHYTgWuACFxyGh2d2bWtnLNBKuzVXHb9Mtqnu842TFCmcOXrDljt6gggtCi35@hkpTTaXgvuuHgHomuF/kXnj/G0@mwV/eDXmEXsziZlHiCalIQJCgNcK8XUOoFWLlF98GllPrhcW3HCZ4IvDuJOwAxxIktP0jstnLX3LXBXY8PUGncteuaumGgZuFQ4WigMWh1P04MZ5qqXqrnKVPIIs255mmb8qfKSMx8PdGOPR8anH3xNmPf50b/H1tz7Rzr20btPn3baKTwcNqm@56ndXOtUNX3l4/0pvFco@ZmP9rftM3z@CDQbY8H6eHZjJRM89zw89/8naTj8Gp1yrIrhGKQD5BCgoFQuJPJy7yBVV4DAY4YPpGdrCrrapk7y2qBLmM4upNj50b@ukJ5LHdtwTEIp6nOm1VRLpAXYuxcV0WJLBssvIFk7/lUyGUEUrOegfX@9rR9eZZowQSs7eujtbmU@zd49wE)

A somewhat interesting formula in there is `(v >> 4) ** 4 >> 14` which turns the leading byte \$v\$ into the number of extra bytes in the sequence.

| v >> 4 | (v >> 4) ** 4 | (v >> 4) ** 4 >> 14 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0b0000 (0x0) | 0b0000000000000000 | 0 |
| 0b0001 (0x1) | 0b0000000000000001 | 0 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 0b1011 (0xB) | 0b0011100100110001 | 0 |
| 0b1100 (0xC) | 0b0101000100000000 | 1 |
| 0b1101 (0xD) | 0b0110111110010001 | 1 |
| 0b1110 (0xE) | 0b1001011000010000 | 2 |
| 0b1111 (0xF) | 0b1100010111000001 | 3 |

### Encoder (123 bytes)

```javascript
a=>a.flatMap(n=>n<192?n:(s=n>>13?n>>20?8:4:2,g=i=>i<s?[...g(i*2),n/i**6&63|n/s**5/i/i&192^128]:[n/s**6&63/s|384/s|192])(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFBbsIwELzzij1UxE5TBycBkoCTU4899RilwoGEGlEHkQghUX5QqZce23/0PXygT6C2QRU9VD14tDszO7uSF3zDm@larNobWc/KY8WOnCWcVEve3vEVkiyRYxp5qYxRw2SSUD9V6PXSMA5iz5kzwRIxbtKMEDJHwvawI11h24PuwH@WbmPbfVe4oqsyHqgX5nFmSC27zbMfBgqVlmNEMT6Osg5ABlnuqAe5c@p6237gQG876Gsc@gYD7flDuZgsCs0VRi@4Rh6ZujJ1cUr513WR6FFqfLOhRt2dMkpP96G5JzKOqbknMr7f6mUerfzArKFVUJzvKQ0RzkyKqU9MZFIqfU8n75CqXt/y6SNCGaijC8gxsAR2KnlZtrAuG2BQIY5HipnWsqmXJVnWczTJ4GqnZPKkvnijZ6ze1oJr2JC2vm/XQs4RHWBMFrWQyHLAwnvIzzM/DrWMQXHZp2B9fb4e3t8UWhCDdfh4sfYTtX@Pj98)

Comment: From what I understand, `g=i=>i<s?`... is an arrow function expression with a ternary condition as it's return value and `n>>13?n>>20?8:4:2` represents a value obtained from two ternary conditions assigned to `s`? Took me a minute to wrap my head around this but wow I'm grateful no one writes code like this in the wild! Great work!

Comment: @Malekai That's correct. [Here](https://tio.run/##VY7dDoIwDIXveYpzZRhBdAMJEoEn8AmMJos/BGOQOOIV7z67nyg2afO1PT3bXb6lOr@6YVz2z8tVa4mqhkxuDznu5RD21AZAjx34VqAhpo5qaSm0FVCoSFPX4CkaR2JNVKBERiliL2xJ2DlPFx05K@/r4jBjIEmSNuwQQbD4b9FjRcdRhBwL5CkmO1FmsrErkwv76xO4KGbHxy@X83d/Bt7SdBPSIvNkvNwtCzkLmNYf) is a formatted version of the source.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 570 bytes

```perl
sub{$_=join'',map sprintf('%08b',$_),@_;%c=qw(00 10 01 11 10 00 11 01);my@r;push@r,oct'0b'.(s/^110(.{5})(..)(.{6})// ? "$c{$2}$1$3":s/^1110(.{4})(..)(.{6})(..)(.{6})// ? "$c{2}$c{$4}$1$3$5":s/^11110(...)(..)(.{6})(..)(.{6})(..)(.{6})// ? "$c{$2}$c{$4}$c{$6}$1$3$5$7":s/.{8}//*$&) while y///c;@r},
sub{map 128^oct"0b$_",map{$_=sprintf"%032b",$c=$_;$c>0xfffff?do{/(..)(..)(..)(...)(.{6})(.{6})(.{6})$/;"01110$4",$1.$5,$2.$6,$3.$7}:$c>0x1fff?do{/(..)(..)(....)(.{6})(.{6})$/;"0110$3",$1.$4,$2.$5}:$c>0xbf?do{/(..)(.{5})(.{6})$/;"010$2",$1.$3}:do{/(.)(.{7})$/;(1-$1).$2}}@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVXbbtpAEH3nK1bbJbaJY@@Czc1y4qrNU6MiRX0jiYWNt6FKgBiiECF/O50dG2wobXp5qQXj2Zlzzngvmp0n6YO70dk4iWfjJDVZMkXH8PXN4jlas9D/NptMNc18HM3JYp5Opkupa3XejTSThYYZhF499p9edM6J4IQLIgQ6XDlcGN7ja5B68@fFfZCas3ip8Uiz9IV9JwTXrbWbGbplwX/dzgzbJheEsnjNmhkTrEX7iEOgUwUeoQADeA7ymLtlKipif2T@pGwuArZdSLGOErPW3cy2G@zEIC/3k4eEvNq2HXtBmpk1tVBqeUSzewczpDxiIVULppavWDNa561mRE0W@yz0WHzOV1I9F@PZ2tZ3n4j/8gtLy2yPcjUf5oCIsJhrsqbF2iZrWayT9VFRHBE8UCt0OCwuyjgo4xYCUZWe701J4qyZc1pZP0epdAfTujhjwrBgAbMgzDaGV3t81ZmE85SmMJCzVK8ReHYHrTaE0fCW@OfKEnJbRPiKc5Mom@dwnA@rIImg7p4tCftY11H5tqtsp4XW2WKP56rsKFLRCBHRSNlRD32JfrRVehtXVY2bmENO4bsVf1T6uUoRl5X4X1ZOkN3FeffymjjvXkfZ/ey2QlMIRI4Ro0bHdqOH9bpjtOhX471ixltNIVsOJoR0osNvrCjF6CcVDYno8vmFHh65oqX965H7H4/RsY3Jdf5sm6uahwtZ6P3GloDGOzI8JuIPeSRC1Y9DrrpP/hLCLMMCIlz5kDgQe7M2yiMzl@R5EeWKstAeAH95tFrSWOOZmSarJZlIkiaSJE9E@zD4eKmR0XRMmIT@jR72dXq2e26m1EOy6nyT6Rx632pu@AG0@yIcfJ0t/RMm9UDljTx8n6wmEhihQaBLkh3TvFHwHLO9Qs7aC0IA8LzsE9SAHECTeJmMVQR8iAANBmDhi0xCMUzVNKgKUrjrtMEnjfQJNHHVn09PPa3RaHwefCEQz7xaVsOCRCXVzQjJy@vrwTW8QRKI9P3VFWBxxnD5FXOo3HY65av6iprbWQWQG/LbLNt8Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 170 bytes

### Decoder, 81 bytes:

```
≔⮌ＡθＷθ«≔⊟θι¿‹ι¹⁹²⊞υι«≔⍘ι²η≔⌕η0ζ≔Ｅ⊖ζ⍘⁺⁶⁴⁰⊟θ²ε⊞υ⍘⁺⁺⭆ε✂κ²¦⁴¦¹✂η⊕ζχ¹⭆ε✂κ⁴χ¹¦²»»Ｅυ⍘ι¹⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNa8JAED2bXzF4moUtrDa1FU8tpSC0EOpRPIQ4NUu3a8wmViz@9u1sYsSUXh7LvI95s1meltk2Nd4/Oqc3Ft9pT6UjnNuirlAICTsxi75zbQhwJ@AnGpyVybbggQTN/EB/AL6Sc6gljKZjISCpXY71mSbjKFg771PqaFGV2m6CYcwpeZB19Iu2a8wlDNWQqeM19ZYW@ExZSV9kK1rjkQVXaYmpHU5iJaGtJ0I6AzUZXae/hgbaQcgnCQujM8JPdkuI@aSQ0c641tz2949Up/g3Ir4o2jbc5BSdooS1VXNPv1H4wQlrZ94vl@pA3EAdHuKA07uA2W3zvg/YZ1crf7M3vw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⮌Ａθ
```

Reverse the input so that the bytes can be easily processed separately.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat while there is still input to process.

```
≔⊟θι
```

Get the next byte.

```
¿‹ι¹⁹²⊞υι«
```

If this is a single byte code, then just push the code, otherwise:

```
≔⍘ι²η
```

Convert the first byte to binary.

```
≔⌕η0ζ
```

Get the total number of bytes in the sequence.

```
≔Ｅ⊖ζ⍘⁺⁶⁴⁰⊟θ²ε
```

Get the remaining bytes, add 640 to each, and convert them to base 2. This results in a string of the form `1XBBCCCCCC`.

```
⊞υ⍘⁺⁺⭆ε✂κ²¦⁴¦¹✂η⊕ζχ¹⭆ε✂κ⁴χ¹¦²
```

Extract the `B` and `C` portions of those bytes, sandwiching the `A` bits from the first byte in between, then convert the final string back from base `2`.

```
»»Ｅυ⍘ι¹⁶
```

Output everything in hex for convenience (decimal would save `4` bytes).

### Encoder, 89 bytes:

```
ＦＡ¿‹ι¹⁹²⊞υι«≔÷Ｌ↨ι²¦⁷θ≔⟦⟧ηＦθ«⊞η﹪ι⁶⁴≧÷⁶⁴ι»≔Ｘ²⁻⁶θθ⊞υ⁺﹪ιθ⁻²⁵⁶⊗θＦ⮌Ｅη⁺κ×⁶⁴﹪⁺²÷ι×θＸ⁴λ⁴⊞υκ»Ｅυ⍘ι¹⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVFPa4MwFD/rp8gxgQyqWMvYaaOXwQrS7SYeXE1NaGaqSVxh9LO791LUQALv5fcvLydZDydT62k6m4HQ9@7qHWWMqDOhH8JaqjhJnlPoFN5K6jlR7CUW2gryF0ev1qq2A5bbq1E1Aihd6yR9q61AJvA42cHugTSjy4oTiXVw7BkKRUFdcnIwjdcGuXnGEBQd6uuDeFStdKsXIh5povuiXZhfMdAUdFTnLc3RebafH1BouFl9ejaj0y3g98Z/a9FALsaWkEcxigGeBFkwZFC4cPKlfgSYZEvscAHu60DUjOqBFsIBWqM2JxkLa5nsBfzucTGozgUnaOEgPx102vAROWaaprLc3NIk2XKyuTU7PLGqqulp1P8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＡ
```

Loop over the input code points.

```
¿‹ι¹⁹²⊞υι«
```

If this is a single byte code point then just push the byte, otherwise:

```
≔÷Ｌ↨ι²¦⁷θ
```

Get the number of additional bytes.

```
≔⟦⟧ηＦθ«⊞η﹪ι⁶⁴≧÷⁶⁴ι»
```

Extract the bottom six bits of those bytes.

```
≔Ｘ²⁻⁶θθ⊞υ⁺﹪ιθ⁻²⁵⁶⊗θ
```

Push the first byte.

```
Ｆ⮌Ｅη⁺κ×⁶⁴﹪⁺²÷ι×θＸ⁴λ⁴⊞υκ
```

For each additional byte, extract its top two bits and push it.

```
»Ｅυ⍘ι¹⁶
```

Output everything in hex for convenience (decimal would save `4` bytes).